# How to start Google Chrome in background on boot?

Tags: google-chrome, google, background-process

How can I start Google Chrome at boot in the background, i.e. not opening an entire window?

Comment: This question on superuser might be useful: [start-google-chrome-in-the-background-in-gnome-do-not-focus-on-the-window](http://superuser.com/questions/354709/start-google-chrome-in-the-background-in-gnome-do-not-focus-on-the-window)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for start in dash

[image]

Open **Startup Applications** and click **Add** button

[image]

Add `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window` to command and chrome-boot (or any name you like) to Name, click Add and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This worked until some chrome versions ago. Now it still works but if you start chrome that way your notifications will pop up in the wrong place (bottom).

To have them at the top right you need to add this:

/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-startup-window

To the startup applications

Answer (score 0):

**Try gDevilspie**

*gDevilspie is a graphical front-end for editing the Devilspie configuration file which allows you to run a particular application within a particular way.*

Install gdevilspie : `sudo apt-get install gdevilspie`

[image]